# Hacksaw replacing "&" with "&amp;"

Tags: plugins, plugin-hacksaw

I'm using the [Hacksaw](https://github.com/ryanshrum/hacksaw) plugin to truncate text and it does a great job except instead of rendering HTML entities such as "&", it's outputting them as "`&amp;`". How can I correct this? Putting them in `allow=""` doesn't work. Do I need to do something to manipulate the text string first before applying the Hacksaw filter? Or is there a Hacksaw option that would correct this?

**Edit for more info...**

Example of text as it should appear:

```
Colour & Light; A House Re-crafted, cover & pg.99-108
```

Example of text output from Hacksaw:

```
Colour &amp;amp; Light; A House Re-crafted, cover &amp;amp; pg.99-108
```

Stupidly I hadn't looked at the HTML until now. It looks like the first `&amp;` is rendering correctly but then there's a second partial entity after it?!

Template code I've tried:

```
{% set summary = article.newsArticle.type('text').first().text|hacksaw(words='35', append='...') %}

{% set summary = article.newsArticle.type('text').first().text|hacksaw(words='35', append='...')|raw %}

{% set summary = article.newsArticle.type('text').first().text|raw|hacksaw(words='35', append='...') %}
```

The order of plugin doesn't appear to have any effect. I get same result with all three of these arrangment above, including no Raw plugin at all.

**Edit for answer**

As per accepted answer below, final working code is:

```
{% set summary = article.newsArticle.type('text').first().text|htmlEntityDecode|hacksaw(words='35', append='...') %}
```

The Craft Helpers plugins did the trick.

Comment: Is this happening for just `&` used in URLs or any `&`?

Comment: @BradBell no not in URLs. Any & in text from Rich Text fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to fight that ampersand with the `htmlEntityDecode` filter that is included in my Craft Helpers plugin https://github.com/carlcs/craft-helpers

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `raw` twig filter.

`{{ variable|hacksaw(words='100')|raw }}`

I did not test this answer since I have't used hacksaw yet. However I believe you can combine filters like this just fine.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

Comment: Thanks @spAnser for the idea but unfortunately it didn't work. The output is still showing the the entity name rather than rendering it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used hacksaw on a few projects, but I haven't come across this before so I can't replicate it. The above answer may work but you could try reordering it to:

```
{{ entry.thing|raw|hacksaw(words='100') }}
```

If this doesn't work, I'll try and replicate it. Can you paste the code for us?

Comment: Thanks Jay. Tried it in that order and still no luck. I've edited my original question with some more details.